# Can I create Custom Java Array that can be created as type array[size]?

Tags: java, c++, arrays

In Cpp++ we can create array as

```
int arr[10];
```

I want to do the same in java without this longer

```
int arr[] = new int[100];
```

Can Create a custom class that allows this ? or Some other way around?

Comment: For me, it is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: @Turing85 in C++, `int arr[10];` declares an integer array of size 10. OP is asking if he could do something like this in java. OP is trying to avoid declaring an integer array this way --> `int arr[] = new int[100];`.

Comment: Yeah @Yousaf is Right

Comment: Short answer to your question is NO and reason is explained in the linked duplicate question

Comment: Nope. This is not possible in java. Also note that `int arr[10];` in C++ allocates stack-memory, while `int arr[] = new int[100];` allocates heap memory. To create an array on the heap in C++, one would write `int * arr = new int[10];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply the answer is No !
Java is purely object oriented so what your trying to achieve is not possible in java .